# Problems making a login script with php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I need some help with my login script for my website. I only get the "nouser" error, but I know that I have an account and it's the right login. It's like it jumps over the login part of the script. And I've checked for curly brackets and I think I have it right. It's like it has problems to extract from the database?

Can anyone see anything that its wrong or can give me tips on how to improve it?

```
if (isset($_POST['login-submit'])) {

        require "dbh.i.php";

        $mailuid = $_POST['mailuid'];
        $password = $_POST['pwd'];

        if (empty($mailuid) && empty($password)) {
            header("Location: ../index.php?error=emptyfields");
            exit();
        } else {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uidUsers=? OR emailUsers;";
            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connect);

            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                header("Location: ../index.php?error=sqlerror");
                exit();
            } else {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $mailuid, $mailuid);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

                if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $pwdCheck = password_verify($password, $row['pwdUsers']);

                    if ($pwdCheck == false) {
                        header("Location: ../index.php?error=wrongpwd");
                        exit();
                    } else if ($pwdCheck == true) {
                        session_start();
                        $_SESSION[userId] = $row['idUsers'];
                        $_SESSION[userUid] = $row['uidUsers'];
                        header("Location; ../index.php?login=success");
                        exit();
                    } else {
                        header("Location: ../index.php?error=wrongpwd");
                        exit();
                    }
                } else {
                    header("Location: ../index.php?error=nouser");
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        header("Location: ../index.php?signup");
        exit(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this part of your code is wrong:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uidUsers=? OR emailUsers;";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connect);
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    header("Location: ../index.php?error=sqlerror");
    exit();
} else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $mailuid, $mailuid);
```

You have only one placeholder to replace in your query: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE uidUsers=? OR emailUsers;`, but you replace it twice:
`mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $mailuid, $mailuid);`

Try and change your query to:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE uidUsers=? OR emailUsers=?;
```

Comment: Thank you, It's working now!

Comment: You could face more problem's with that logic in the future too, because of the OR operator on your query this could return more than 1 if your user table is "not properly populated".  I would suggest to review that point to avoid some headaches on the future.